# after receiving soap response modify xml and send to anther service using http adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

while using http adapter I need to call first service that return XML,
after receiving the response I want to change values and send back to anther service,
how can I do it ?
do http adapter has json to xml function ?

Comment: would you please make it simpler. what do you mean by http has json to xml function and why you need that?

Answer (score 2):

WL adapter will automatically convert XML to JSON for you, however it doesn't have any manual JSON<->XML conversion APIs.

In your case possible solution might be to retrieve XML as plaintext by supplying returnedContentType:"plain" in invocation options. Alter whatever you need using regex/string replace. Use resulting string in 2nd procedure invocation as post body.

Alternatively, you can use 3rd party library to parse/convert/do whatever you need with XML, e.g. http://www.json.org/java/ (more info about how to use it in your adapter - http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/04_08_Using_Java_in_adapters.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

After checking number of solutions, I state the the http result will be a plain text,
then made a call to java function sending the xml as String, and used 
javax.xml to hold and alter the XML.
XPath to retrieve the correct node using org.w3c.dom.*

Hope this will help you too.